# R - Fast data.table cell paste based on group

Tags: r, data.table, paste

I have a big `data.table` where I want to paste the cells of a column, based on the group provided by the `by` argument, and collapse them with a `;`.

```
proteinNames <- c("Protein A", "Protein A", "Protein A", "Protein B", "Protein B")
uid <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 3)
score <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
dat <- data.table(Name = proteinNames, UID = uid, Score = score)
dat
#         Name UID Score
# 1: Protein A   1     1
# 2: Protein A   1     2
# 3: Protein A   2     3
# 4: Protein B   2     4
# 5: Protein B   3     5

test <- dat[, .(Score = paste(Score, collapse = ";")), by= .(Name, UID)]
test
#         Name UID Score
# 1: Protein A   1   1;2
# 2: Protein A   2     3
# 3: Protein B   2     4
# 4: Protein B   3     5
```

However, I am sure there is a way to push its limits to run faster (takes about 7 seconds). Is there any other way that I am not aware of?

**UPDATE 2**

I did a benchmarking of `paste` vs `toString` vs `str_c` on an old 4GB Ubuntu machine with the original data and the results show that `paste` is actually the fastest:

```
2 test.data[, .(Score = str_c(Score, sep = ";")), by = .(Name, UID)]

1 test.data[, .(Score = paste(Score, collapse = ";")), by = .(Name, UID)]

3 test.data[, .(Score = toString(Score)), by = .(Name, UID)]


  replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child

2          100 1019.576       1  1018.144     0.74          0         0

1          100 787.961        1   787.016    0.508          0         0

3          100 1556.145       1  1544.048     2.48          0         0
```

Comment: Perhaps, you can try `toString()`. I am using this regularly as aggregation function but I have not benchmarked it yet.

Comment: `stringi::str_c` is *slightly* faster on my machine. How often are you doing this operation? 7 second run time is not bad...

Comment: Indeed str_c is from **stringr** package. Right now I am benchmarking my implementation vs the toString. Indeed maybe the optimization is an overkill as it is a  one time operation.

Comment: @dayne Any idea why the str_c is slighty slower on my benchmark?